# Do html 5 videos buffer on page load or only when playing the video?

Tags: html, html5-video

If I wanted to embed 20 videos on a page will they all start buffering on page load or will they wait until they are played/interacted with for the first time? If they buffer on load how could I circumvent this until I want to display the video? I don't want a user to be buffering 20 videos when they may only be watching one or even none at all.

Comment: See the preload attribute at http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/video.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the `preload` attribute of HTML5 `video` tag. Here is the [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp). Basically there are three options :

```
 auto - when browser should load the entire video when the page loads
 metadata - when browser should load only metadata when the page loads
 none - when browser should NOT load the video when the page loads
```