# iPad HTML web page issue

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, fullpage.js

I am trying to get to the bottom of an issue on a 4th generation iPad issue we are having. We keep getting the following error and the page refreshes so there is no way to debug this in developer tools on a mac:

**"A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded"**

The page uses fullpage.js and renders 22 separate html5 (mp4) videos that run in the background of each full page/section.

***Weirdly, if we change the code to only render say 15 videos the page works fine!***

The videos are between 500KB and 3MB each. The videos are 33MB in total.

They are embedded like this:

```
<video id="video-transport" class="video-bg">
  <source src="videos/videoname.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
  <source src="videos/videoname.webm" type="video/webm">
  <p class="vjs-no-js"></p> 
</video>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions of what is wrong with the page? Is there some kind of upper memory limit or page size we are exceeding.

Is there an easy way of debugging this?

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: _"Weirdly, if we change the code to only render say 15 videos the page works fine!"_ - I can't imagine why you would find this weird. 22 videos playing on a single page is crazy for a mobile device.

Comment: @Turnip not only this, but 33 MB is insane for a website.

Comment: Just to be clear, if it makes any difference, the web page is an online learning resource that will be only available over a closed high end wireless network and not over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why it's breaking, but...

Have you tried using the [`preload` property](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp) for the videos to prevent loading them on page load ? 
[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790108/1081396)

Or, if that doesn't workf for you, have you though a about using the fullpage.js [lazy loading option](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#lazy-loading) the videos?

```
<video>
    <source data-src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source data-src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Hi @Alvaro thanks for this the lazy loading option,this really helped here and the page can now load. FYI I had just coded something similar to get around the issue. But this is far easier to implement.

The issue I have now though is that as the numerous videos load the iPad eventually falls over as it seems to run out of memory??

BTW unfortunately it would seem that you cannot use the preload property on iOS?

Comment: Is there and easy way to destroy the videos and release the memory after the page /section has unloaded. I tried clearing the source src attributes and removing all of the source tags within the video tag that are not currently being viewed, but the memory doe not seem to be released?? I also tried to load() them after clearing the src's but jQuery seem to throw a "indexOf" (although this could be something in my code).